# How to dynamically add objects to children in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I think it's better if I explain what I really want. This is what my database looks like:
[image]

I want to add the Tournament Status for every tournament that is created, but I'm facing a problem in data retrieval. I have a custom class called UserInformation which I use with the dataSnapshot.getValue() method, but I'm not sure how to dynamically add the tournament objects (with the 2 booleans) to the user. I've tried adding an arraylist of said objects, but this is not reflected in the database.

This is my code for creating a user:

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailId, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        String userId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

                        DatabaseReference currentUser = mDatabase.child(userId);
                        currentUser.child("name").setValue(name);
                        currentUser.child("studentNumber").setValue(studentNumber);
                        currentUser.child("faculty").setValue(mFaculty);
                        currentUser.child("email").setValue(emailId);
                        currentUser.child("isGod").setValue(false);
                        currentUser.child("tournamentStatuses").setValue(new ArrayList<TournamentStatus>());

                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"User successfully registered\nLogged in as "+name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
```

My hunch is that the issue is with the ArrayList.
Also, even if I'm able to add the user, how would I retrieve a particular tournament status?

Here's my UserInformation class:

```
public class UserInformation {

    public String name;
    public String studentNumber;
    public String faculty;
    public boolean isAdmin;
    public String email;
    public boolean isGod;
    public ArrayList<TournamentStatus> tournamentStatuses;

    //Define this constructor
    public UserInformation() {
        // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(UserInformation.class)
    }


    public boolean isGod() {
        return isGod;
    }

    public void setGod(boolean god) {
        isGod = god;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getStudentNumber() {
        return studentNumber;
    }

    public void setStudentNumber(String studentNumber) {
        this.studentNumber = studentNumber;
    }

    public String getFaculty() {
        return faculty;
    }

    public void setFaculty(String faculty) {
        this.faculty = faculty;
    }

    public boolean isAdmin() {
        return isAdmin;
    }

    public void setAdmin(boolean admin) {
        isAdmin = admin;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public ArrayList<TournamentStatus> getTournamentStatuses() {
        return tournamentStatuses;
    }

    public void setTournamentStatuses(ArrayList<TournamentStatus> tournamentStatuses) {
        this.tournamentStatuses = tournamentStatuses;
    }
}
```

Is there a way around this, or should I change my database design?

Comment: Humm, I don's see that your db design and objects in java are the same. Your user->tournamentStatus doesn't contain multiple tournament information. Thus it is not filling the ArrayList  inside the userInfo . Please add the Tournament class too.

Answer (score 1):

To make your job easier, you need to change a little you database design. In stead of `tournamentStatuses` use the `tournamentId` directly as the name of the node like this:

```
Firebase-root
    |
    ---- Tournaments
    |       |
    |       ---- //
    ---- Users
            |
            ---- userId
                   |
                   ---- // user details
                   |
                   ---- tournamentId
                             |
                             ---- isOrganizing: false
                             |
                             ---- isPaticipating: false
```

In this way you can query your database more easy like this:

```
DatabaseReference yourRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(uid).child(tournamentId);
```

Second, in order to write data objects into your Firebase database, in stead of using a `List`, use a `Map`. You need to make this change in your pojo and also when you'll use `setValue()` method.

Hope it helps.